# c++14 - Is this a good way to prepend a char on a string?

Tags: c++, string, performance, c++14

If I wanted to add char c onto the beginning of string s, is the following good practice?

```
string s = "oo";
char c = 'f';
s = c + s;
```

In the Question "*[Prepend std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468597/prepend-stdstring)*" on SO the answers that suggested doing this were less well received than the top answer, which suggested using the member-function `.insert()`.

Is there a reason besides efficiency (`s = c + s` is not efficient since all the contents of `string s` must be copied)?

Comment: It might not be efficient, but there's no way insert can achieve this differently than by shifting the other contents forwards. You could even argue this is a superslightly bit faster since it doesn't have to check whether to shift the characters before the first character

Comment: @Athosvk: though unless it is handled by SSO, using `+` will always need to allocate a buffer.

Comment: The efficiency argument is basically it: your addition `+` allocates an unnecessary temporary object (and at least under gcc/clang, the generated assembly is really ugly). But note that e.g. `c + std::move(s)` could be equivalent to using `insert()`. The `insert()` probably still has to reallocate the internal string buffer (assuming no small-string optimization is involved) so not much will be won either way. This is unlikely to be an issue, so move on to more important problems :)

Comment: @amon Imo that’s a good answer. Why did you post it as a comment?

Comment: @besc Writing a good answer is harder than writing a comment. Also, I don't write answers for questions where I'd voted to close. Why did I close? The scope of this site is more about software engineering concepts and design level questions. This question is clearly code-level, and such questions would be a better fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both perform the same operation, what reason could there be *besides* efficiency? `c+s` will create a temporary string, thus requiring a copy of every character in both `c` and `s`, and potentially a heap allocation. The temporary will then be moved into the given object, which will have its current memory deallocated (if any). These are not cheap operations.

By contrast, `insert` will *only* perform a heap allocation if there is insufficient capacity for the new character. You'll still have the copying going on, since you're inserting at the beginning. But that's about it. It is as efficient as insertion at the head of a contiguous array gets.

Answer (score 2):

The `s = c + s` operation would create a temporary object probably dynamically allocating memory on heap. Do the required append operation and then copy it back to the string variable. More number of instructions and memory operations are involved.

Memory operations like allocating and de-allocating memory are costly. 
Insert would reallocate memory only if not enough contiguous memory is available for the string. Worst case it would still match to `s = c + s` approach.

Although it is not much of a performance issue (considering the worst case) it is more elegant and easy to understand from a programmers perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Note also that there is nothing to stop an implementation of string from allowing limited appends at both ends without needing to move the contents. The default implementations do not do this, but some implementation might reserve extra space at the front of the string the first time you prepend, so that a subsequent prepend is "free". There are vector implementations that do this out there.