# Memory Limit Exceeded in C++ but not in Python

Tags: python, c++, memory

I am working on question [1249. Minimum Remove to Make Valid Parentheses](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-remove-to-make-valid-parentheses/) on LeetCode. It is an easy question which I can solve with stack in both C++ and Python. However, my C++ version code leads to **Memory Limit Exceeded**, while my exact same Python code only consumes 15.3 MB memory. Could anyone help me understand what is wrong, please?

C++ code:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string minRemoveToMakeValid(string s) {
        stack<pair<char, int>> stack;
        for (int i=0; i<s.size();i++){
            if (s[i]!='(' && s[i]!=')')
                continue;
            else{
                if (!(stack.empty()) && stack.top().first=='(' && s[i]==')')
                    stack.pop();
                else
                    stack.push({s[i],i});
            } 
        }
        string res;
        for (int i=s.size()-1; i>=0;i--){ 
            if (!stack.empty() && i==stack.top().second)
                stack.pop();
            else{
                res = s[i] + res;
            }
        }
        return res;
            
    }
};
```

Even if replace stack data structure in C++ with vector, it still leads to Memory Limit Exceeded.

Python3

```py
class Solution:
    def minRemoveToMakeValid(self, s: str) -> str:
        stack = []
        for i, c in enumerate(s):
            if c!="(" and c!=")":
                continue
            if stack and stack[-1][0] == '(' and c==")":
                stack.pop()
            else:
                stack.append([c,i])
        
        res =""
        for i in range(len(s)-1,-1,-1):
            if stack and i == stack[-1][1]:
                stack.pop()
            else:
                res = s[i] + res
        return res
```

[image: LeetCode results showing Memory Limit Exceeded]

Comment: Maybe using `stack` as both a class name and variable name is giving you grief?

Comment: Could it be because `stack` implementation in C++ grows faster and goes beyond the limit? Do you want to try `vector` and see what happens? In Python, you're using a list and use it as a stack?

Comment: not sure if thats the problem, but `s.size()-1` is wrong. When the size is `0` then `s.size()-1` wraps around to the largest unsigned value

Comment: @MarkRansom using stack as variable is not the issue, I saw many people do that. After renaming stack variable to st, nothing changed.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it is guarantted that 1 <= s.length <= 10^5, so ````s.size()-1```` is not the cause here

Comment: @aminrd after replace stack data structure with vector in c++, it still leads to ````Memory Limit Exceeded````, could you please help further?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change the c++ method signature to: `string minRemoveToMakeValid(const string& s){`? Is this allowed on `LeetCode`?

Comment: @quamrana ````string minRemoveToMakeValid(const string& s){```` still leads to ````Memory Limit Exceeded````

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468597/prepend-stdstring) help with memory? Perhaps: `string res; res.reserve(s.size());` might also help.

Comment: @quamrana ````string res; res.reserve(s.size());```` does not help, still causing Memory Limit Exceeded

Answer (score 2):

This is another guess about what could reduce the memory footprint.

I guess that each `res = s[i] + res;` may repeatedly reallocate memory resulting in `res` being over allocated above what is needed.

The code below (I'm hoping) makes far fewer allocations, each of an exact size needed at the time:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    std::string minRemoveToMakeValid(std::string s) {
        std::stack<std::pair<char, int>> stack;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            if (s[i] != '(' && s[i] != ')')
                continue;
            else {
                if (!(stack.empty()) && stack.top().first == '(' && s[i] == ')')
                    stack.pop();
                else
                    stack.push({ s[i],i });
            }
        }
        std::string res(s.size(),' ');
        auto iter{ s.size() };
        for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!stack.empty() && i == stack.top().second)
                stack.pop();
            else {
                //res = s[i] + res;
                res[--iter] = s[i];
            }
        }
        return res.substr(iter);

    }
};
```

Comment: It does create a load of unnecessary strings, though I would expect RAII to immediately destroy them and not use much extra memory overall.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I have this nagging suspicion that LeetCode may be overestimating the amount of memory used.

Comment: it seems that ````res = s[i] + res;```` is the cause of  Memory Limit Exceeded, but I can't understand why. I could understand that ````res = s[i] + res;```` may be slower than ````res = res + s[i] ;````, as the latter runs in O(1), but why they differ in memory usage?'

Comment: Are you saying that LeetCode accepts this code? Does it give a size of memory used?

Comment: yes, leetcode accepted your answer! Yes, your code used 13MB

Comment: both ````res = res + s[i];```` and ````res = s[i] + res;```` cause Memory Limit Exceeded,.

Comment: Ok, my suspicion is that LeetCode may be totalling up all the sizes of the allocations made, ignoring the common practise of many allocators which is to reuse recently deleted memory. `res = s[i] + res;` will make *a lot* of allocations, roughly n^2 bytes where `n==s.size()`.

Comment: @quamrana are you saying this is Leetcode's problem, not the internal issue of C++ language? I guess I will try to profile this code in CLion to see how much memory on earth it uses.

Comment: Yes, but this is pure conjecture. If you are going to the trouble of profiling, you could simulate what I suspect by collecting a redundant vector of strings of the intermediate values of `res` to see how much memory *could* be wasted by an inefficient allocator.